# how to stop the count from going negative when the value is zero?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to create an add to card button but I'm stuck on the count going negative,basically when we click on remove item at  value  zero its goes negative(-1)  since I have just started learning vuejs and this is totally new to me so any help would be apreciated!

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    increment() {
      this.count++
    },
    decrement(){
      this.count--
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.increment()
    // this. decrement()
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <div class="btn-container">
    <!-- <button class="button"> count  is : {{ count }}</button><br> -->
    <button class="button"  @click="increment">add to cart</button>
    <button class="button"  @click="decrement">remove item</button>
  </div>
  <h1 v-if= count> item added {{count}} </h1>
    <h1 v-else-if = count> please add item </h1>
  <h1 v-else> no item </h1>
</template>

<style>
  .btn-container{
    align-items:"center";
    justify-content:"center";
    display: flex;
    padding:5px;
    margin:5px;
    background-color: red;
  }
  .button{
    padding : 1vw;
    margin: 1vw;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    border-radius: solid 1px;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check if count is greater of 0 before substract:
(as commented if you want to disable(or maybe hide) decrement button when count is 0, you can bind disabled or use v-show)

```js
const { reactive, onMounted } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    increment() {
      this.count++
    },
    decrement(){
      this.count > 0 && this.count--
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.increment()
    // this. decrement()
  }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```css
.btn-container{
    align-items:"center";
    justify-content:"center";
    display: flex;
    padding:5px;
    margin:5px;
    background-color: red;
  }
  .button{
    padding : 1vw;
    margin: 1vw;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    border-radius: solid 1px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div class="btn-container">
    <!-- <button class="button"> count  is : {{ count }}</button><br> -->
    <button class="button"  @click="increment">add to cart</button>
    <button class="button" :disabled="!count"  @click="decrement">remove item</button>
  </div>
  <h1 v-if= count> item added {{count}} </h1>
    <h1 v-else-if = count> please add item </h1>
  <h1 v-else> no item </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I would also suggest making the button disabled if the count is 0: `<button class="button"  @click="decrement" :disabled="count == 0">remove item</button>`

Answer (score 2):

I think we can just disable the remove button if there is no item in the cart.

```
<button class="button" :disabled="!count"  @click="decrement">remove item</button>
```

Live Demo **:**

```js
const { onMounted } = Vue

const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    increment() {
      this.count++
    },
    decrement(){
      this.count--
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.increment()
  }
})
app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="btn-container">
    <!-- <button class="button"> count  is : {{ count }}</button><br> -->
    <button class="button"  @click="increment">add to cart</button>
    <button class="button" :disabled="!count" @click="decrement">remove item</button>
  </div>
  <h1 v-if= count> item added {{count}} </h1>
  <h1 v-else-if = count> please add item </h1>
  <h1 v-else> no item </h1>
</div>
```

***Update :*** As per author's comment, Here is the working demo.

```js
const { onMounted } = Vue

const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0,
      decrementClicked: 0,
      msg: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    increment() {
      this.count++;
      this.msg = '';
    },
    decrement() {
      if (this.count > 0) {
        this.count--;
        if (this.count === 0) {
          this.msg = 'no item ';
        }
      } else {
        this.decrementClicked++;
        this.msg = (this.decrementClicked === 1 && !this.msg) ? 'no item ' : 'Please add Items in your cart';
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.increment()
  }
})
app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="btn-container">
    <button class="button"  @click="increment">add to cart</button>
    <button class="button" @click="decrement">remove item</button>
  </div>
  <h1 v-if="count"> item added {{count}} </h1>
  <h1 v-if="msg">{{ msg }}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: any idea when double clicked it will show please add item!

Comment: @Aahad where you want to apply `double clicked` functionality ?

Comment: on remove item!

Comment: @Aahad I did not get it. Can you please explain more better.

Comment: when we remove all items it shows no item and when it shows no item when we again try to remove clicking on it then it will show please add items

Comment: @Aahad I added the code snippet as per this requirement. To achieve this no need to disable the button. We can simply stop the negative counter and show the message `Please add items`. I hope it will work as per your expectation.

Comment: ok its showing no item but when i click again on remove item button the text will change from no item to please add item! appreciate if you can help!

Comment: @Aahad Done with the change request. Please have a look in the code snippet. I hope it will work as per your expectation.

Comment: bro from where did you learn these basics!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251378/discussion-between-rohit-jindal-and-aahad).

Comment: bro from where did you learn these basics!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps You can just add a condition in `decrement` method to check first if the `count` is already `0`, if it is `0` then do not decrement, if not `0` decrement by `1`

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    increment() {
      this.count++
    },
    decrement(){
      this.count = this.count === 0 ? 0 : this.count - 1
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.increment()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `watch` the property

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    increment() {
      this.count++
    },
    decrement(){
      this.count--
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.increment()
    // this. decrement()
  },
  // Watch the count property and validate it
  watch: {
    count(newVal, oldVal) {
      this.count = newVal < 0 ? 0 : newVal
    }
  }
}
```

Or you can not allow the value to be decremented if the new value will be negative.

```js
methods: {
    decrement(){
      this.count = this.count - 1 < 0 ? 0 : this.count--  
    }
}
```

Adding the check on the `decrement()` method is recommended instead of the `watcher` method.